# "...can't figure out the architecture type of..." problem when compiling Python C-extension with gcc

Tags: gcc, osx-lion, python-c-extension

I just upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion, and an old python c-extension that I had to update didn't want to compile properly. I don't really know what to do here. Anyone who could help me out so it compiles ok? It compiled just fine back in Snow Leopard.

```
Home:folder Me$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'ccookies' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c ccookies.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/ccookies.o
llvm-gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/Developer/usr/bin//../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/powerpc-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:630,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:28,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:312,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                 from ccookies.c:5:
/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:109:14: warning: #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/_t/yg4wppss5fv6dkmh89_6ykm40000gn/T//cc3Cgr3v.out
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 255
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You appear to be using a 32-bit Python 2.7, possibly installed from python.org.  Because of changes in Xcode 4 (dropping of support for the 10.4u SDK and gcc-4.0) it is not practical to build C extension modules with that Python on 10.7 Lion.  Either use the Apple-supplied Python 2.7 (`/usr/bin/python2.7`) or install the [python.org 64-bit/32-bit installer](http://python.org/download/) for 2.7.2 instead of the 32-bit-only one.

Comment: Yup, installing the 32/64 bit 2.7.2 version solved it. Thanks much!

Comment: Great.  BTW, if you plan to use Tkinter or IDLE, you should also install the latest ActiveState Tcl/Tk 8.5, if you can.  The Apple-supplied version in 10.7 still has a few old bugs.

Comment: My problem is slightly different but I have tried many of the suggested gcc related pil/pillow installation fixes. Following the advice here, I installed python 64/32 (2.7.5) as recommended, but I'm not sure if I actually have it running or if the old one is still on (interpreter gives `Python 2.7.5 (v2.7.5:ab05e7dd2788, May 13 2013, 13:18:45`. However, I think this is the 32/64 python and I still get a gcc problem. Full problem description is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18950383/770513    I am on OS X 10.6.8. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install pynauty on my Mac OS X 10.7 and I got this problem. For some reasons, Ned Deily's answer didn't help me. I just want to provide one more way to solve this problem in case someone come to this page and is in the same situation as I am. The way I solved this prolem is:

Before running "python setup.py build", run:
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

Answer (score 0):

On travis, I was getting this error.  I've been using `osx_image: osx10.11` since forever, but it suddenly stopped working, with this error, in last ~few weeks.  Changing to `osx_image: xcode7.3` fixed the error for me.