# Pillow virtualenv install fails: "command 'gcc-4.2' failed"

Tags: python, django, gcc, mezzanine, python-imaging-library

I am installing [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/overview.html) in a virtualenv. It fails at the [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) installation with a gcc-4.2 related error of which this is an excerpt. I can actually install it successfully on my machine but not inside of a virtualenv. I want it in a venv however. What should I do?

```
`decode.c:465: error: ‘COMPRESSION_SGILOG’ undeclared (first use in this function)

decode.c:468: error: ‘COMPRESSION_SGILOG24’ undeclared (first use in this function)

decode.c:471: error: ‘COMPRESSION_CCITTRLEW’ undeclared (first use in this function)

In file included from decode.c:416:

libImaging/TiffDecode.h:10:20: error: tiffio.h: No such file or directory

libImaging/TiffDecode.h:13:18: error: tiff.h: No such file or directory

In file included from decode.c:416:

libImaging/TiffDecode.h:30: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before     ‘tdata_t’

libImaging/TiffDecode.h:43: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘ttag_t’

decode.c: In function ‘PyImaging_LibTiffDecoderNew’:

decode.c:444: error: ‘COMPRESSION_CCITTRLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)

decode.c:444: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

decode.c:444: error: for each function it appears in.)

decode.c:447: error: ‘COMPRESSION_CCITTFAX3’ undeclared (first use in this function)

decode.c:450: error: ‘COMPRESSION_CCITTFAX4’ undeclared (first use in this function)

decode.c:453: error: ‘COMPRESSION_OJPEG’ undeclared (first use in this function)

decode.c:456: error: ‘COMPRESSION_ADOBE_DEFLATE’ undeclared (first use in this function)

decode.c:459: error: ‘COMPRESSION_THUNDERSCAN’ undeclared (first use in this function)

decode.c:462: error: ‘COMPRESSION_DEFLATE’ undeclared (first use in this function)

decode.c:465: error: ‘COMPRESSION_SGILOG’ undeclared (first use in this function)

decode.c:468: error: ‘COMPRESSION_SGILOG24’ undeclared (first use in this function)

decode.c:471: error: ‘COMPRESSION_CCITTRLEW’ undeclared (first use in this function)

lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccaRiavj.out

error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /Users/m/.virtualenvs/slinc/bin/python -c "import     setuptools;__file__='/Users/m/.virtualenvs/slinc/build/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-77NDIT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/m/.virtualenvs/slinc/bin/../include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/m/.virtualenvs/slinc/build/pillow
Storing complete log in /Users/m/.pip/pip.log`
```

Answer (score 3):

try that in you linux console and then try again:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: i'm on mac and can't find any suitable substitute to this.

Answer (score 0):

Install the commandline tools for XCode.

```
Open XCode > Preferences > Downloads
```

Comment: I think I already have them since `which gcc` returns `/usr/bin/gcc`. I have `gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666)`. Nevertheless, I tried to download them again but had to use a different technique as my Xcode version 3.2.6 doesn't have that preference. I followed http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/55344. I get the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 20 need to install

```
yum install python-devel
```