# 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1 when installing bcrypt

Tags: python, bcrypt

Hi all im new to django and python trying to install bcrypt which is needed for building a piece of django code im trying to run on my system, im running into a problem as below

im using python 2.7 and v1.4 django

```
running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'bcrypt._bcrypt' extension

gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/bcrypt/bcrypt_python.o

In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:4,

                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:85,

                 from bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:17:

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory

In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:4,

from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:85,

from bcrypt/bcrypt_python.c:17:

/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory

lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/2s/n9wb5x4534nfs1cbrlph32v00000gp/T//ccb7N3qq.out

error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /Users/Kinnovate/Downloads/dwaiter-django-bcrypt-913d86b/my_new_env/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/Kinnovate/Downloads/dwaiter-django-bcrypt-913d86b/my_new_env/build/py-bcrypt/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/2s/n9wb5x4534nfs1cbrlph32v00000gp/T/pip-yONWs2-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /Users/Kinnovate/Downloads/dwaiter-django-bcrypt-913d86b/my_new_env/bin/../include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1
```

how do i fix this?

Comment: What platform are you on? (Windows, OSX, Linux; version thereof?) How are you trying to install `bcrypt`? Specific steps you tried, please. Log output is fine but we need to know what command or sequence of commands preceded it.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316583/lipo-cant-figure-out-the-architecture-type-of-var-folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
```

I believe `stdarg.h.` is part of the standard C library, `libstdc` (or possibly the standard C++ library `libstdc++`.) This smells to me like `libstdc` is missing or not located where the compiler thinks it is.

Googling your error message (`stdarg.h: No such file or directory`) produces a stack of hits on StackOverflow and elsewhere. See [here](http://binarylionstudios.com/blog/2011/01/30/error-stdarg.h-no-such-file-or-directory/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832294/pil-installation-fails-missingstdarg-h) for what appear to be exact solutions to your problem.